# How to create a derived list of distinct items using Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

Let's say I have an `IReactiveList<string>` named `Items` from which I'd like to create some derived list `DerivedItems` (of type `IReactiveList<string>` or `IReactiveDerivedList<string>`) *of distinct items only.*

`Items.CreateDerivedCollection(...)` has all the bells and whistles I'd like to use, but it doesn't appear to have an option for filtering out duplicates.

I tried `Items.Distinct().CreateDerivedCollection(...)`, but `CreateDerivedCollection()` no longer tracks changes when used with `Distinct()`.

I tried `Items.Changed.Throttle(...).Subscribe(_ => ResetImpl())` where `ResetImpl` clears `DerivedItems` and adds each item in `Items` one-by-one, but then I get exceptions stating that the enumeration cannot complete because the collection was modified.  (This occurs primarily when I add dependencies on `DerivedList`.)  I can add a lot of locks but this seems pretty messy.

Finally I tried manually triggering off `Items.IsEmptyChanged.Where(b => b)` and `Items.ItemsAdded` in an attempt to manually synchronize `Items` and `DerivedItems`, but here I run into a lot of timing issues where list clearing and item addition do not consistently happen in the right order.

I get the feeling I'm missing an easy solution to this problem.  How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a way of doing it, but it's not using IReactiveDerivedList:

```
var distinctElements = Items.Distinct().ToList();
Items.Changed.Subscribe(y =>
{
    distinctElements = Items.Distinct().ToList();
});
```